# Activating Items on a Listview

Tags: android, listview, colors, background, listadapter

i am a new android developer and i am trying to build a similar app to "List17.java"
in the apiDemos,
anyway, i have created my own listitem that i use instead of "simple_list_item_activated_1"
and added the row:
     android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
in order to get selected items to remain colored after they are selected just like in list17,
but for some reason it does happen, the selected item's background changes back right after you click it,
i tried putting a static background color to all the items using:
    android:background="#FF0000"
and it worked,
any idea what am i missing?
[List17.java](http://source-android.frandroid.com/development/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List17.java)

Comment: see this ,,,http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-customized-listview.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a selector XML file and set that to android:background in you're layout XML.